# Concept of modules in c

Tags: c

I am going through C++ FAQ by cline. It discusses about how C++ classes are better than "C-style modules". One can refer the text [here](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=T-nwI02AULUC&pg=PA102&lpg=PA102&dq=When%20a%20module%20dreams%20about%20growing%20up,%20it%20dreams%20of%20being%20a%20class&source=bl&ots=TP7j_1NNs5&sig=6r8WQaQNRQWg6do4WQOrEA83KkY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=CSQIT_vyJofQrQf4vOXZDw&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA).

But it doesn't discuss what a "C module" actually is. I read some texts on the net, but none of them dealt with the topic.

Can anyone explain these concepts further?

Comment: As far as I know, it's a group of functions (and probably types) that do a logically related work. You can see Linux-Kernel modules as a live example :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C does not have a concept of modules, as such. It has the concept of "translation unit", which is (roughly) the `.c` file plus the contents of the headers it includes, directly or indirectly. The translation units get compiled independently, and then linked together into an executable program.

A translation unit gives a little bit of namespace management: you can define names of functions and variables as `static`, so that they're only visible inside the translation unit. This is much less helpful than, say, C++ classes, where name conflicts are easier to avoid.

Look at languages like, say, Python, for even better solutions for that.

Comment: Lars's answer is excellent. Take a look at the definition that Wikipedia has: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_programming. Perhaps a main goal of modular programming is to allow modules to be interchanged because they do closely-similar jobs.